# Como obtener una consulta en eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

estoy mostrando los datos de acciones personales pero quiero mostrar el nombre del titulo la cual esta relacionado con empleados como podria hacer la consulta para mostrar ese campo de titulos (nombre) que al seleccionar una accion me tirara el nombre de ese titulo del empleado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la consulta que realizo pero me tira un valor nullo

```
 $titulo = \DB::table('acciones_personales')
            ->join('empleado', 'empleado.id', '=', 'acciones_personales.nombre')
            ->join('titulos', 'titulos.id', '=', 'empleado.titulo_obtenido')
            ->select('titulos.nombre as nombre_titulo','titulos.id','acciones_personales.id')->where('titulos.id',$id)->where('acciones_personales.id',$id)->first();
           dd($titulo);
```

esta es mi tabla de empleados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es mi tabla de acciones personales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas haciendo el join entre empleado y acciones personales por id y nombre, debes comparar el id en ambas tablas

Comment: De primera instancia, no estás usando `Eloquent`, sólo estás usando el "fluent query builder", te recomendaría usar Eloquent realmente para evitarte los `join`, además de un código más limpio, por otro lado, te está devolviendo nulo ya que hay algo mal en tus llaves foráneas, deberías de mostrar ejemplos de registros (al menos uno), para poder ver si estás realizando las uniones correctamente.

Comment: @zerocool Estaría mejor que subiera un ejemplo, porque si te fijas el campo `nombre` de la tabla `acciones_personales` es de tipo entero, así que no sabemos si la llave foránea sea en realidad correcta o no... debemos de fijarnos más bien por el tipo de dato y no por el nombre de la columna.

Comment: Si eso es cierto, presumi que era un error en su modelo y que debajo de la imagen donde no se ve estaría el foreign key. Como te dice @AarónGutiérrez sube los datos a ver

Comment: @zerocool Aunque de cualquier forma, no sé que gestor esté usando, pero para poder realizar una llave foránea correctamente, las columnas de la tabla hijo y padre deben de ser del mismo tipo de dato, longitud, entre otras características... ahí está uniendo un entero de 150 dígitos (es imposible que un `integer` almacene más de 11 dígitos) con otro entero de 11 dígitos. Así que probablemente por ahí va el error.

Comment: ahorita actualize los datos revisen porfavor

Comment: Bueno creo que debes revisar lo que te comentó @AarónGutiérrez sobre el tipo de campo nombre en acciones_personales, ese campo debería llamarse id_empleado (esto es cosa tuya)...

Comment: ya lo corregi a los 2 campos de tipo int longitud 11

Comment: pero me sigue con lo mismo

Comment: ya lo resolvi ahi dejo lo que hice gracias por su apoyo

Answer (score 0):

esta era la consulta correcta

```
$titulo = \DB::table('acciones_personales')
            ->join('empleado', 'empleado.id', '=', 'acciones_personales.nombre')
            ->join('titulos', 'titulos.id', '=', 'empleado.titulo_obtenido')
            ->select('titulos.nombre as nombre_titulo')->where('acciones_personales.id','=',$id)->first();
           dd($titulo);
```